# Is there a non-regular strictly positive finite Borel measure on a compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

By strictly positive I mean $\mu(U)>0$ for any open set $U$.
Does there exist any such a measure?
What if the space is a topological group?